# Permission denied while starting a flask app at port 80 in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: python, flask, amazon-ec2

I have developed a flask based app which is running successfully at my local machine / network.

I deployed it to an AWS EC2 instance. Started it like this:

```
flask run --host <private ip within AWS>
```

but when I tried to access an implemented API through Postman, I got following error in Postman console:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <IPv4 Public IP within AWS>
```

Noticed that it might be due to the fact that flask app typically runs on port 5000, however the EC2 has inbound rule of type http bound to port 80.

So I changed my flask code to:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='<private ip within AWS>', port=80)
```

And tried to run it like this in AWS ec2 instance:

```
python3 apiapp.py
```

However I got following stack trace while trying to run the app:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "apiapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    app.run(host='<private ip within AWS>', port=80)
  File "/home/ec2-user/AwesomeAPIs/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/flask/apiapp.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/ec2-user/AwesomeAPIs/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/home/ec2-user/AwesomeAPIs/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1005, in inner
    fd=fd,
  File "/home/ec2-user/AwesomeAPIs/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 848, in make_server
    host, port, app, request_handler, passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd
  File "/home/ec2-user/AwesomeAPIs/venv/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Am I missing anything obvious over here?

Comment: This is a priviliged port, meaning you need special permissions to use it. Also, using flask built-in development server for production purposes is a bad idea

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will look into using appropriate server at production. So shall I configure special permissions in security groups of my EC2 instance, to make it working?

Comment: normally, you use production-grade software, like nginx+uwsgi, to serve flask applications. Most Linux distributions already have preconfigured permissions for this software, so you don't have to write your own apparmor/selinux profile

Comment: The issue you're running into is nothing to do with AWS security groups. It's all about low-numbered ports on Linux which require root access (which you should *not* use to run your app). Read about gunicorn and uWSGI.